# R beamer numbering in default theme

Tags: r, latex, beamer

I am looking for a solution on how to force slides numbering in R's beamer_presentation with theme set at "default".

So far, I have found a solution but under them "metropolis". If I just type "default" instead of "metropolis", there is an error.

```
---
title: "**TITLE**"
subtitle: "Subtitle"
author: "Name"
institute: ""
date: January 25, 2022
output:
  beamer_presentation:
  theme: "default"
  keep_md: true
  keep_tex: no
  latex_engine: xelatex
  includes:
     in_header:
  incremental: no
classoption: aspectratio=169
header-includes:
    - \usetheme[numbering=fraction]{metropolis}
    - \def\ps@navigation@titlepage{\setbeamertemplate{footline}{}\@nameuse{ps@navigation}}
---
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Beamer actually has a very handy macro to add frame numbers: `\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame numbers]` to the footline

```
---
title: "**TITLE**"
subtitle: "Subtitle"
author: "Name"
institute: ""
date: January 25, 2022
output:
  beamer_presentation:
    keep_tex: true
header-includes:
  - \setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]
---

ttt
```

[image]

(needs rmarkdown v2.11.15 or newer)

Comment: Thank you very much for your prompt support!

Comment: @Alex You're welcome!